# formating string and passing argument at runtime

Tags: python, string, format

eg-In this instead of using 21 (a value), I want to use a variable to generalize it

`print("{:-^21}".format(".|."*(2*(i+1)-1)))`

I want to use something like this

`print("{:-^M}".format(".|."*(2*(i+1)-1)))`

Answer (score 1):

That can easily enough be done.  For example:

```
M = 40
i = 3

print("{val:-^{width}}".format(width=M, val=".|."*(2*(i+1)-1)))
```

Outputs:

```
---------.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.----------
```

You could also do it with f-strings (note the outer `'` because `"` is used on the inner expression):

```
print(f'{".|."*(2*(i+1)-1):-^{M}}')
```